# Excel multiple if statements with more than 2 answers

Tags: excel

trying to get an excel spreadsheet to do what I need and im basically computer illiterate. Any help would be appreciated
Basically what I need is the below statements combined

```
If E8 = Officer and G8 = Active Duty then 1
If E8 = Officer and G8 = Active Reserve then 2
if E8 = Enlisted and G8 = Active Duty then 3
If E8 = Enlisted and G8 = Active Reserve then 4
```

Ive been able to figure out some basic and, if statements but this one with multiple outcomes is throwing me for a loop, Also it all needs to go into one cell if possible. Thanks guys

Answer (score 4):

```
=MATCH(E8&G8,{"OfficerActive Duty","OfficerActive Reserve","EnlistedActive Duty","EnlistedActive Reserve"},0)
```

OR

```
=(MATCH(E8,{"Officer","Enlisted"},0)-1)*2+MATCH(G8,{"Active Duty","Active Reserve"},0)
```

Comment: Very creative.  Should be noted that if 1,2,3,4 are just symbolic result values that you may want to pair the formula with a CHOOSE function.   Having said that it does answer the question and I I like it!

Comment: @ForwardEd I would use INDEX instead of CHOOSE but dealers choice.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
IF(AND(E8="Officer",G8="Active Duty"), 1, 
      IF(AND(E8="Officer",G8="Active Reserve"), 2, 
               IF(AND(E8="Enlisted",G8="Active Duty"), 3, 4)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use this quite a lot in the future, better to set up as a table to look up and here is how you can do it with an array formula (click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> together):

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$5,MATCH(E2&F2,$A$2:$A$5&$B$2:$B$5,0),1)
```

[image]

This way, you can dynamically update your criteria any time you want.

Plus, you can set up a drop down list from your criteria like this (`Data > Data Tools > Data Validation`):

[image]